# How to recursively delete a binary tree on visual C++ 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

The following code worked on Linux, but crashed on windows:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    Node()
        :data_(0), left_(nullptr), right_(nullptr)
    {   }

    int data_;
    Node* left_, *right_;
};

struct Tree
{
    Node* root_;

    ~Tree()
    {
        release(root_);
    }

    void release(Node* node)
    {
        if (node)
        {
            release(node->left_);
            release(node->right_);
            delete(node);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        auto tree = Tree();
    }
    std::cout << "exit\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using g++ 4.82:

> exit

Crashed on Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2013, complained like:

> Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x009A5CCC : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0.

How to understand this problem?How to fix it?

Comment: You should use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root_` member of `Tree` is not initialized. Trying to delete it is undefined.

You should initialize it in the constructor:

```
Tree() : root_(nullptr) {}
```

Comment: You are right..It's working now. But why it's working on Unbuntu? Anything like run time checking on windows?

Comment: @YueWang it's not working on Ubuntu either. It just appears/pretends to be working. Undefined behavior doesn't mean "guaranteed crash". (man, if only it did!)